# JS Galaxian Shooter enemies shooting

Tags: javascript, list

Hey i'm trying to make a super simple Galaxian Shooter game. I'm having a problem in making all the enemies in the enemy list shoot separately. Right now, only one shoots bullets. I know there are a lot of better ways to do things in this code, I just haven't made it efficient yet and I'm fixing it all so please don't say anything about that. Lines 193,86,72, and 42 all have something do with the enemyBulletList, if that helps.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    keys = [];
    width = 500;
    height = 500;
    bulletList = {};
    enemyBulletList = {};
    enemyList = {};
    enemyAmount = 10;

var player = {
    x:400,
    y:450,
    speedX:7,
    speedY:7,
    width:32,
    height:32,
    hp:3,
    shootCdTimer:0,
    shootCd:1,
};

tickShootCooldown = function(){
 player.shootCdTimer--;
}
    setInterval(tickShootCooldown,500);
    
onGameStart = function(){
 generateEnemy();
    generateBullet();
    generateEnemyBullet();
    setInterval(changeEnemyDirection,2000);
    setInterval(changeEnemyDirection2,4000);
}
    setTimeout(onGameStart,0);

Bullet = function(id,x,y,speedX,speedY,width,height) {
    var asd = {
        x:x,
        y:y,
        speedX:speedX,
        speedY:speedY,
        name:'B',
        id:id,
        width:width,
        height:height,
        color:'black',
    };
    bulletList[id] = asd;
}
generateBullet = function() {
    var x = player.x;
    var y = player.y;
    var width = 5;
    var height = 15;
    var id = Math.random();
    var speedX = 0;
    var speedY = 15;
    Bullet(id,x,y,speedX,speedY,width,height);
}
EnemyBullet = function(id,x,y,speedX,speedY,width,height) {
    var asd = {
        x:x,
        y:y,
        speedX:speedX,
        speedY:speedY,
        name:'B',
        id:id,
        width:width,
        height:height,
        color:'black',
    };
    enemyBulletList[id] = asd;
}
generateEnemyBullet = function() {
    for(var key3 in enemyList){
        var x = enemyList[key3].x;
        var y = enemyList[key3].y;
    }
    var width = 5;
    var height = 15;
    var id = Math.random();
    var speedX = 0;
    var speedY = -15;
    EnemyBullet(id,x,y,speedX,speedY,width,height);
}
    
Enemy = function(id,x,y,speedX,speedY,width,height) {
    var asd = {
        x:x,
        y:y,
        speedX:speedX,
        speedY:speedY,
        name:'B',
        id:id,
        width:width,
        height:height,
        color:'red',
    };
    enemyList[id] = asd;
}
generateEnemy = function() {
    var x = 50;
    var y = 50;
    var width = 32;
    var height = 32;
    var id = 1;
    var speedX = 2;
    var speedY = 0;
    Enemy(id,x,y,speedX,speedY,width,height);
    Enemy(id*2,x*2,y,speedX,speedY,width,height);
    Enemy(id*3,x*3,y,speedX,speedY,width,height);
    Enemy(id*4,x*4,y,speedX,speedY,width,height);
    Enemy(id*5,x*5,y,speedX,speedY,width,height);
    Enemy(id*6,x,y*2,speedX,speedY,width,height);
    Enemy(id*7,x*2,y*2,speedX,speedY,width,height);
    Enemy(id*8,x*3,y*2,speedX,speedY,width,height);
    Enemy(id*9,x*4,y*2,speedX,speedY,width,height);
    Enemy(id*10,x*5,y*2,speedX,speedY,width,height);
}
changeEnemyDirection = function() {
    for(var key in enemyList){
        if(enemyList[key].speedX > 0){
            enemyList[key].speedX *= -1;
        }
    }
}
changeEnemyDirection2 = function() {
    for(var key in enemyList){
        if(enemyList[key].speedX < 0){
            enemyList[key].speedX *= -1;
        }
    }
}

    
function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillRect(player.x,player.y,player.width,player.height);
    
    if(enemyAmount < 1){
        generateEnemy();
        enemyAmount = 10;
    }
    
    if(player.x < player.width/2){
        player.x = player.width/2;
    }
    if(player.x > width - player.width){
        player.x = width - player.width;
    }
    if(player.y < height-150){
        player.y = height-150;
    }
    if(player.y > height-32){
        player.y = height-33;
    }
    
    if (keys[39]) { //right arrow
            player.x+=player.speedX;
    }
    if (keys[37]) { //left arrow
            player.x-=player.speedX;
    }
    if (keys[38]) { //up arrow
            player.y-=player.speedY;
    }
    if (keys[40]) { //down arrow
            player.y+=player.speedY;
    }
    if (keys[32]) { //space bar
            if(player.shootCdTimer<=0){
                generateBullet();
                player.shootCdTimer = player.shootCd;
            }
    }
    
    for(var key in bulletList) {
        updateEntity(bulletList[key]);
    }
    for(var keyy in enemyBulletList) {
        updateEntity(enemyBulletList[keyy]);
    }
    
        for(var key2 in enemyList) {
            var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(bulletList[key],enemyList[key2]);
            if(isColliding) {
                delete enemyList[key2];
                enemyAmount --;
                delete bulletList[key];
                break;
            }
        }
    
    //for(var key3 in enemyList){
        var timer = Math.random();
        if(timer <= 0.01){
            generateEnemyBullet(enemyList[key2]);
        }
   // }
    
    for(var key in enemyList){ //change to collision with enemy bullet
        updateEntity(enemyList[key]);
        var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(player,enemyList[key]);
        if(isColliding){
            player.hp = player.hp - 1;
        }
    }
    
    
    ctx.fillText(player.shootCdTimer,5,10);
}
    setInterval(update,20);
    

testCollisionEntity = function (entity1,entity2){       //return if colliding (true/false)
        var rect1 = {
                x:entity1.x-entity1.width/2,
                y:entity1.y-entity1.height/2,
                width:entity1.width,
                height:entity1.height,
        }
        var rect2 = {
                x:entity2.x-entity2.width/2,
                y:entity2.y-entity2.height/2,
                width:entity2.width,
                height:entity2.height,
        }
        return testCollisionRectRect(rect1,rect2);
       
}
testCollisionRectRect = function(rect1,rect2){
        return rect1.x <= rect2.x+rect2.width
                && rect2.x <= rect1.x+rect1.width
                && rect1.y <= rect2.y + rect2.height
                && rect2.y <= rect1.y + rect1.height;
}

    
    
updateEntity = function(something){
 updateEntityPosition(something);
 drawEntity(something);
}

updateEntityPosition = function(something){
 something.x += something.speedX;
    something.y -= something.speedY;
}

drawEntity = function(something){
 ctx.save();
 ctx.fillStyle = something.color;
 ctx.fillRect(something.x-something.width/2,something.y-something.height/2,something.width,something.height);
 ctx.restore();
}


 
    
    
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Comment: The `for` loop in `generateEnemyBullet()` doesn't make sense: each iteration overwrites the previous iteration's `x` and `y` values but doesn't do anything with the `x` and `y`, so then the call to `EnemyBullet()` only uses the last enemy's `x` and `y`. Perhaps the rest of the lines in that function are supposed to be inside the loop?

Comment: I've been trying new stuff out but I just can't get it to work. Do you have any other ideas or maybe you can test it out for yourself? @nnnnnn